# how to work with other base numbers in java?

Tags: java, int

Guys if the int c=10001; which is a binary value.If i want to process it like multiplying it by 10 how to do that?

Comment: Is this for an academic or real-world context, i.e., do you **really** need to treat an int as binary?

Comment: Senthil: int c = 10001;` is not a binary value, it is a decimal value.

Comment: @Oscar Reyes it is a binary value: 0b10011100010001

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to do this: `Integer.parseInt("10001", 2)`, which will give you 17.
`Integer.toString` also accepts radix as second argument.

Doc: [Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Answer (score 7):

an "int" is neither binary, hex or decimal, it's just a place to store a number.  Variables themselves don't have a specific hex/dec/binary representation until you print them.

When you type the number into your code it has a base, but after it uses the base to process what you typed, the base is thrown away and the int just stores a number.

So the answer to your question is c * 10 (assuming you meant 10 dec)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify it as `int c = 0x11` (consider 10001 is 0001 0001, which is 11 in hex)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int c = 0x11; // 10001
    int d = 10; // ten decimal
    int d = 0x2; // ten binary 0010 - see table below
    System.out.println(c);
    System.out.println(c*d);
  System.out.println(c*e);  
}
```

binary-decimal conversion

- 0 0000
- 1 0001
- 2 0010
- 3 0011
- 4 0100
- 5    0101
- 6    0110
- 7    0111
- 8    1000
- 9    1001
- A       1010
- B         1011
- C    1100
- D    1101
- E     1110
- F        1111

Answer (score 0):

Treating

```
int c = 10001;
```

as a binary number is really bizarre.  It would be better to instead declare it as a String

```
String binaryString = "10001";
```

and then looping through each character to perform whatever base conversion algorithm you want.

Answer (score 0):

The multiplication of a binary with an integer:

- If it's a power of two, then just left-shift all digits to the exponents value left
- If it's not a power of two find the biggest power of two smaller then the value you want to multiply your c with. The do the same for the remainder and so on. At the end just sum up all values.

For your example with c=10001 (base 2) * 10 (base 10) this means (10 = 2^3+2^1)

```
int c=10001
int result=c*1000+c*10 //left-shift 3 + left-shift 1
```

But this is really not a good way to handle this kind of task...
Moreover it think it's a bad idea to save an binary value into an int. I think it would be better to convert the binary into an integer before using it.